# Opening python file with readlines() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

The folder with this project contains a plain text file with a DNA sequence in fasta format ('MYH7.fasta').

Complete the cell below to open and read the file using the readlines() method and to save the sequence to a string named DNAsequence.

NB: The parts to be completed are indicated with "...". The other parts should not be changed.

```
inFile = ...

DNAsequence = ''

for ... in ...:

 if not(">" in Line):

if (len(Line) > 0):

 DNAsequence = DNAsequence + Line

print(DNAsequence)

print(len(DNAsequence))
```

Comment: Try to improve your questions with a code that can be executed by others. [mcve]

Comment: @DanielGL: but this is not a question. It is an *assignment*.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer they are looking for is

```
inFile = open("MYH7.fasta", "r").readlines()
```

In Perl concatenating code is standard (example below). I'm not sure here because inFile.readlines() should construct an array based on carriage returns and the invariable code in your question doen't allow its functionality to be used. The following code answers your question leaving the file handle open and omits readlines().

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
inFile = open("MYH7.fasta", "r")

DNAsequence = ''

for Line in inFile:
    if not(">" in Line):
        if (len(Line) > 0):
            DNAsequence = DNAsequence + Line

print(DNAsequence)

print(len(DNAsequence))
```

The Perl version shows how several commands can be concatenated in a single line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $DNAsequence;
open (IN, "<MYH7.fasta");
while (my $line = <IN>){
    chomp $line;
    next if $line =~ m/>/;
    $line =~ m/[ACGT]{10}/i ? $DNAsequence .= $line : next;
   }
close IN;
print $DNAsequence, "\n", length($DNAsequence) . " and Python s\*\*ks\n";
```

The MYH7.fasta input file will be of format,

```
>example_sequence
ACGCGTAGACGTATAG
```

I think there is a bug in your code because if carriage returns are present within the sequence they will carry through into the variable DNAsequence. In Perl these are removed using "chomp" or can by explicitly removed with $_ =~ s/\n// (or in this eg $line =~ s/\n//;). The presence of "\n" could complicate subsequent analysis.